# How can I change view to orthographic using a menu?

Tags: unity, c#, scene, menu

I'm writing the custom menu using `MenuItem` and I'm stuck trying to make scene view orthographic when `5` is pressed. What is the object or method I can use to set scene's view to orthographic (I don't mean the main camera, but the main view shown in the window).

This is a C# code of what I was trying to achieve:

```
[MenuItem("View/SetOrtho _5")]
static void SetOrtho() {
    var scene = ... //assign scene
    scene.setOrtho(true); //set orthographic view to the scene
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneView.html) is for Unity 2019, so it’s not clear whether this applies to 2018 or older, but it’s worth a shot.

The gist is

```
 UnityEditor.SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.orthographic = true;
```